# Call to HttpWebRequest from a Command in a ViewModel (MVVM)

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

I used the MVVM Pattern for my App, at first time. I create a view class, a viewModel class an Command class. When I click in the view on a Button, I start the binding Command in my viewModel. In this Command I create an HttpWebRequest, to load news from a Webservice as json-object. In the method 'GetNewsResponseCallback' I get my data as a json stream. The seriallisation works fine. When I in this method call the 'PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("News"))', I get a COMException. But I need the PropertyChange event to Update the Listview in my view. How can I resolve this problem? It is correct to start a service from my command? I´m very new to develop with teh MVVM-Pattern. In the following my code:

> ```
> <Canvas>
>     <Button Content="Aktualisieren"
>             Canvas.Top="20"
>             Canvas.Left="600"
>             Command="{Binding SynchronizeNewsCommand}"/>
>
>     <ListView x:Name="viewBox"
>               ItemsSource="{Binding News}"
>               ItemTemplate="{StaticResource newsTemplate}"/>
>
> </Canvas>
> ```

```
public class MyCommand<T> : ICommand
    {
        readonly Action<T> callback;


        public MyCommand(Action<T> callback)
        {
            this.callback = callback;
        }


        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }


        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;


        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            if (callback != null) { callback((T)parameter); }
        }

    }



public class NewsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public ObservableCollection<NewsSerializer> News { get; set; }

        public MyCommand<object> SynchronizeNewsCommand { get; set; }


        public NewsViewModel()
        {
            SynchronizeNewsCommand = new MyCommand<object>(SynchronizeNews);
        }


        private void SynchronizeNews(object obj)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Constans.uri);
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetNewsRequestStreamCallback), request);
        }


        private void SynchronizeFinished(object obj)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("News"));
        }


        private void GetNewsRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
            request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetNewsResponseCallback), request);
        }


        private void GetNewsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

            // End the operation
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
            Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();

            DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<NewsSerializer>));
            News = (ObservableCollection<NewsSerializer>)ser.ReadObject(streamResponse);

            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("News"));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, when using an ObservableCollection - you do not recreate it every time. You should call Clear() instead (or remove deleted items) and then add new items to it one by one. Your view will be notified of the changes automatically and you wont need to invoke PropertyChanged

```
    private void GetNewsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

        // End the operation
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
        Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();

        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<NewsSerializer>));
        var res = (IList<NewsSerializer>)ser.ReadObject(streamResponse);

        News.Clear();
        foreach(var item in res)
        {
            News.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

In your case, you should also consider extending ObservableCollection class by implementing AddRange method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My View Model is in a Portable class library, which used for a win 8 app and win phone app. My view is in the win 8 ans win phone projects. I think it is the best way to bind a Collection to my ListView. From my viewmodel I don´t can get my ListContro from the view.

Comment: And you dont need to. My point was, that you should not reassign your News property. You should avoid creating new observable collection. Reuse the existing one instead by using News.Clear(), News.Remove(...) and News.Add(...).

Comment: But this method don´t update the ListView-Control in my view.